# Vite Rollup build issue result in incorrect image source path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite, rollup

I'm new to Vite and currently running into this build issue.

I have an internal image React component in which I am referencing in my project.

After build, the component renders as below

```
<img class="image" src="/assets/photo.svg" alt="" />
```

But i need to change the src path from `/assets/photo.svg` to `./assets/photo.svg` as my test environment is not located at the root of the domain.

running localhost is fine as it is going off the root domain but in my test environment the images don't load up because of this incorrect path.

Is there a way for me to change this path reference without having to modify the internal component?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Vite, you will have a `vite.config.js` file. Inside that file, you can set the base URL for your assets. You can find more information [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base)

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
  ...
  base: './',
};
```

Comment: For me that leads to Vite adding full path from drive to the result! That is, "../../../../my_projects/my_project/assets/index-923869f3.js" Looks as complete nonsense